# How do I POST boolean data to Flask route

Tags: python, forms, flask, routes, request

I want to pass a variable called `manual` to Flask a route, which will then do something based on the value in the POST form data. But the forms data is interpreted as `string` in flask even though I send it in a form as a dictionary.

here's the code

```
@app.route("/result", methods= [ 'POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    manual = request.form.get("manual")
    if manual is None:
            return "manual is required"
```

here's how I am sending the data

```
r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/result'
                 ,data={manual':False})
```

I understand that I can do something like;

```
if manual == 'True'
```

but I don't want to be comparing strings, I want to do it in the standard way whichever it is.

Thanks

Comment: Are you even posting your data? It looks like a get request and in that instance the variable is passed in the URL and will be a string by default

Comment: I want to see the returned response too, that is why I use ```requests.get()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do a **POST** request, not a GET:

```
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/result', json={'manual': False})
```

Then (untested):

```
@app.route("/result", methods=['POST'])
def result():
    json_data = flask.request.json
    manual = json_data.get("manual")
    if manual is None:
            return "manual is required"
```

Have a look at the doc for details: [More complicated POST requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

Note that there are differences between using the data parameter and the json parameter. An important thing to note is the presence of the Content-Type header:

> Using the json parameter in the request will change the Content-Type
> in the header to application/json.